# Match-Search function in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, search

So I've got 2 columns. Column "Mess" has gazillions of random numbers x digits long. Column "Check" has specific sorted numbers. Now I make a 3rd column called "boolean".

I want a function to check every number from column "Check" against Column "Mess" and output in the field in column "boolean" true or false if checked number exist in the "Mess" coulumn.

How do I do that with excel? I don't think Excel has a function for that, or does it?

Comment: In case I've missed something, in what way do you want this to be recursive?

Comment: Nothing, I was reading code in another source code and messed up what I wanted. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MATCH` to do most of the work. For `Mess` in Column A and `Check` in B, you can use the following to generate your TRUE/FALSE match values.

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$1000,0)))
```

This returns `TRUE` if the `Check` value is found in `Mess` and `FALSE` if it's not found.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use `COUNTIF`:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$1000,B2)>0
```